# Testing with AutoFixture with real Database without mocking

Tags: c#, autofixture

I am developing an ERP that is not based on EF. My question is: how can I do perform test using AutoFixture for all the CRUD without using doing mocking? How can I perform cleanup and Setup operation for Unit Test.

Likewise, I need to test update and delete operation  alone with insert. What I have seen on different site there are only insert fixture examples without using mock.

Comment: IIRC, the [Outside-In Test-Driven Development](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/outside-in-tdd) Pluralsight course by @MarkSeemann shows how to setup and teardown a database using tests written with xUnit.net.

Comment: (As a side note, I thought that ERPs are now written with [this DX machinery](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Application_Framework/demos.xml)...)

Comment: FWIW, I wrote [an outline of how to write automated tests against SQL Server back in 2006](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ploeh/2006/11/17/data-access-component-testing), but as pointed out by @NikosBaxevanis, the [outside-in course](http://www.shareasale.com/r.cfm?u=1017843&b=611266&m=53701&afftrack=&urllink=www.pluralsight.com/courses/outside-in-tdd) contains the most up-to-date example I've published on the topic.

Comment: The Outside-In TDD we are creating  and dropping database for every single test which will slow down test performance and effectiveness